# Display sidebar after x paragraphs

Tags: wordpress, sidebar

I am looking for a way to display a sidebar dynamically after x number of paragraphs in my content.

**Problem :** `dynamic_sidebar (' name ')` doesn't display text : `var_dump($ad_code)` = `bool(true)`. 
**Result :** My sidebar is displayed twice in the header, once before the content and at the right paragraphs it displays the number "1".

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'prefix_insert_post_ads' );

function prefix_insert_post_ads( $content ) {   
    $ad_code = dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-6' );

    if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
        return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 1, $content );
    }
    return $content;
}

function prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content ) {
    $closing_p = '</p>';
    $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
    foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {

        if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
        }

        if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;
        }
    }

    return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just add this :

```
ob_start();
dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-id');
$sidebar = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

It's working !